Omit first mark when pathreplacing in TikZ
I want to omit the first tick mark when doing a pathreplacing operation in TikZ. The first mark is interfering with the points connecting various directed line segments.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (3.14,2.71);
    \fill (A) circle(0.1);
    \draw[blue,->,shorten >=0.1cm,shorten <=0.1cm] (A) -- ++(60:2.5) coordinate(B);
    \fill (B) circle(0.1);
    % The following line decorates the blue arrow
    % with red tick marks. I want to remove only
    % the first tick.
    \draw[red,thick,decoration=ticks,segment length=1cm,decorate] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Modification 1
I tried using circular nodes per a comment, but the tick marks were just shifted by the radius of the node:


The easiest thing would be to fill the circle as the last thing (change drawing order).

@MS-SPO I made the circles big for the picture so you guys could see them better. In my actual diagram, they are smaller than the tick marks.

Where do the dots come from? If you use nodes of shape circle and draw the line between them, you don't need shorten and the decoration doesn't decorate a line that isn't there. Alternatively, use pre and pre length: \draw[red, thick, decoration={ticks, pre=moveto, pre length=1cm, segment length=1cm}, decorate] (A) -- (B);

@Qrrbrbirlbel Two problems occurred when I tried this: (1) the decoration starts at the beginning of the path anyways, so it just places the first tick on the edge of the circular node, and this even affects the second tick by pushing it farther than it should be (I'll post a picture); and (2) the minimum size parameter doesn't seem to make the node the right size.

Decoration is not always easy to control. So you could avoid it and set the few ticks by hand or loop.

Both the inner seps (default 0.3333em) as well as the minimum width/minimum height (default 1pt for some reason) affect the size of nodes. Set inner sep to zero (and outer sep as well if you don't draw the border and just fill the circle) and then minimum size (which sets both minimum width and minimum height) controls the diameter.

Let me ask counter questions: Where should the ticks be? What do the circles represent? It seems the pre length neds to be set to 1cm − the radius of the circles, if you want it to be 1cm away from the center of the node. Maybe an alternative way of drawing the ticks is better here.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Sorry for the delay, I was away from the computer for a bit. The circles represent points on a grid. I connect them with a directed line segment to represent a geometric vector (I'm typesetting my linear algebra notes). The tick marks are there for measurement. Stylistically, I think it looks better when the first and last ticks are ommitted (which is done automatically for the last one anyways). And thank you by the way for your comment on node sizing.

Maybe you can use the TikZ library decorations.markings
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

with something like
decoration={%
  markings,% switch on markings
  mark=% actually add a mark
      between positions 1cm and 1 step 1cm
      with
      {
        \draw[thick, red] (0pt,-1mm) -- (0pt,1mm);
      }
}

Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (3.14,2.71);
    \fill (A) circle(0.1);
    \draw[blue,->,shorten >=0.1cm,shorten <=0.1cm] (A) -- ++(60:2.5) coordinate(B);
    \fill (B) circle(0.1);
    \draw[%
      decoration={%
        markings,% switch on markings
        mark=% actually add a mark
            between positions 1cm and 1 step 1cm
            with
            {
              \draw[thick, red] (0pt,-1mm) -- (0pt,1mm);
            }
      },
      decorate
    ] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


